# Traverse elements collectively in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have 7 text-fields in my JSP. In my javascript quite often I need to **collectively** fill these textfields, empty, validate, etc.

So presently in my JS I keep their id's as **parameter_1, parameter_2, etc** as it helps me to traverse them together easily using id property.

**JS:**

```
function emptyThresholdTextFields(){    
    $('[id^="parameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}


function fillThresholdTextFields(data){        
    $("[name='minNumberOc']").val(data.minNumberOc);
    $("[name='minDurationOc']").val(data.minDurationOc)
    $("[name='maxNumberIc']").val(data.maxNumberIc)
    $("[name='maxDurationIc']").val(data.maxDurationIc)
    $("[name='maxNumberCellId']").val(data.maxNumberCellId)
    $("[name='distinctBnumberRatio']").val(data.distinctBnumberRatio)
    $("[name='minPercentDistinctBnumber']").val(data.minPercentDistinctBnumber)
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<s:textfield id="thresholdParameter_1"
        label="Minimum Number of OG Calls" required="true"
        name="minNumberOc"
        onkeypress="return isNumber(event,'thresholdParameter_1')">
</s:textfield>
```

1. Is this a good practice to keep id's like in this form parameter1, parameter2, etc?
2. As in `fillThresholdtextFields` for filling I have to access each parameter associatively. So later on if parameters increase it will get more cumbersome. Is there some other alternative such that both 1 and 2 can be achieved easily?

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be descriptive, so using parameter1, parameter2, etc, is not good practice.  For emptying all of the fields you can simple grab them all at once and set their value.  ex.

```
$("input[type='text']").val("");
```

This will set the val to an empty string for everything it matches.  If you have multiple forms on the page, you may want to scope it down to a particular one, ie.

```
$("#someform input['type=text']").val("");
```

For #2, if each of those fields needs to be set to something different, you'll likely need to access each separately.  But if some are the same, you could use the same technique above for setting some of them at the same time.  Using a class for instance.

```
$(".min-oc").val(data.somevalue);
```

Setting each element with a class of "min-oc" in this instance.